# Notation regarding random variables

Tags: notation, random-variables, elementary-probability

Let X be a random variable.

Consider X ~ F. It can be read as X has **distribution** F.

What is distribution referring here? Consider the following interpretations

1) If X is continuous, then F is a probability density function and if X is discrete then F is a probability mass function.

2) F is a cumulative distribution function.

Which of the above is correct? If not, what is the distribution the notation referring to?

Comment: 2) is correct. There are many CDF's which are neither discrete nor have  a density so 1) is not the correct interpretation.

Comment: A distribution is a distribution. A distribution has pdf and cdf (at least it may have those, particularly if $X$ takes values on the real number line), but neither of those is what a distribution _is_.

Comment: @Arthur Would you take that comment a step further and state what a distribution is?

Comment: @littleO No. I don't think I'm capable of that. Probability theory was never something I actually studied. I have just picked up tidbits here and there.

Comment: I like this question and think it is important because I think the word "distribution" or "probability distribution" is used inconsistently in textbooks, and especially in online discussions, and this has caused genuine confusion. There has been a bit of a pedagogical failure with the word "probability distribution".

Answer (score 7):

Suppose that $X$ is a real-valued random variable. There are some probability textbooks which use the term "distribution of $X$" to refer to the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X$. In these books, the expression $X \sim F$ often means that $F$ is the CDF of $X$. I suspect this is the case in your example.

However, I think the most standard definition of "the distribution of $X$" is the probability measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb R$ induced by $X$:
$$
\mu(A) = P(X \in A)
$$
for any measurable set $A \subset \mathbb R$.  For example, this definition is used in Folland.

Answer (score 3):

In most places where I see the $X \sim \square$ notation, my answer would be "neither." The thing in the $\square$ is neither a pdf nor a cdf.

I often see probability distributions specified in a format like this:

$$  X \sim N(0,1).$$

This says that the random variable $X$ has a standard normal distribution
(a normal distribution with mean zero and variance $1$).

I do not recall ever seeing $N(0,1)$ used as the name of a function.
In my experience it is neither the pdf of the standard normal distribution nor the cdf of the standard normal distribution.
It is merely the name of the distribution itself, which can be identified either as the continuous real-valued distribution with the pdf
$$ f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} e^{-x^2/2} $$
or the real-valued distribution with the cdf
$$ F(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{-\infty}^x e^{-t^2/2} dt. $$

Comment: I think it'd be helpful to state explicitly what a distribution is.

Comment: @littleO I don't think I can do better than the definition you gave in the second part of your answer (as found in Folland). My answer is mainly a remark on the _notation_ in the question.